# using google maps on cordova application

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have been working on hybrid application development and web application using cordova, jquery and backbonejs.

I have the following features to be implemented.

```
1. adding markers
2. Overlaying list window
3. Overlaying pie-chart
4. Define/add/remove/change geo-fence using polygons
```

I have two options to implement the google maps v3 in the application.

1. Using jquery-map-ui v3
2. Directly loading the map from the google server

Which option is the best one to implement ?

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is only tagged for android I would suggest you to use https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin. It provides a javascript wrapper to leverage the native Google Maps on iOS and Android. It supports a lot of features out of the box, like markers, polygon drawing, several types of overlays, etc If you are not targeting other platforms than Android or iOS I would certainly use this one as, being native, it is very responsive.

Answer (score 0):

If your map needs complex customization(customized popup, customized icons, customized lines etc), my suggestion is the section 2 because you could get many 3rd party plugins to work with your app.

However, there is no doubt that if you only need a simple map, jquery-map-ui is a better option.